# How to add new attribute to hyperlink using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder how can we add new attribute to hyperlink using JQuery i tried various selection methods but none of them working on my html code

html code

```
<a href="https://useotools.com/contact#faq" class="current"><i class="menu_icon blank fa"></i><span>FAQs</span><span class="plus"></span></a>
```

js code

```
 jQuery(window).load(function () {
 // if contain contact#faq
 jQuery('a[href~="contact#faq"]').prop("onclick", "window.location.href='https://useotools.com'; return false;");

 // if url equal to 
  jQuery('a[href="https://useotools.com/contact#faq"]').prop("onclick", "window.location.href='https://useotools.com'; return false;");

 // if url end with
   jQuery('a[href$="contact#faq"]').prop("onclick", "window.location.href='https://useotools.com'; return false;");

  // if url start with
   jQuery('a[href*="useotools.com/contact#faq"]').prop("onclick", "window.location.href='https://useotools.com'; return false;");

 });
```

codepen : https://codepen.io/Zelda99/pen/poJxmEL

Comment: Stop trying to fiddle with “attributes”, and add event handling the _proper_ jQuery way. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @CBroe that onClick attribute is my fix to prevent ajax redirection to webpage because some scripts were not loading due to it

Comment: Then you should properly describe what _actual_ problem you are trying to fix in your question right from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector was ok. Using prop to change onclick not ok.

Your `jQuery(window).load(function () {})` is incorrect too, it should be 
`jQuery(window).on('load',function () {})`

I prefer `$(function() {})`

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href$="contact#faq"]')
    .css("background-color","red") // check the selector is ok
    .attr("onclick", "window.location.href='https://useotools.com'; alert('bla'); return false;");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://useotools.com/contact#faq" class="current"><i class="menu_icon blank fa"></i><span>FAQs</span><span class="plus"></span></a>
```

I prefer on click

```js
$(function() {
  $(".current").on("click", function(e) { // or $("[href$='contact#faq']").on()
     // if (this.href.indexOf("contact#faq") !=-1) this.href = 'https://useotools.com'; 
     if (this.hash==="#faq") this.href = 'https://useotools.com'; 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://useotools.com/contact#faq" class="current"><i class="menu_icon blank fa"></i><span>FAQs</span><span class="plus"></span></a>
```

To change location you can do

```js
$(function() {
  $("[href$='contact#faq']").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link click
    location = 'https://useotools.com'; 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://useotools.com/contact#faq" class="current"><i class="menu_icon blank fa"></i><span>FAQs</span><span class="plus"></span></a>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#link1").prop("onclick","alert(this.href); return false");
  $("#link2").prop("onClick","alert(this.href); return false");
  $("#link3").attr("onClick","alert(this.href); return false");
  $("#link4").attr("onclick","alert(this.href); return false");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://google.com" id="link1">prop onclick Not ok</a><br/>
<a href="https://google.com" id="link2">prop onClick Not ok</a><br/>
<a href="https://msn.com" id="link3">attr onclick works</a><br/>
<a href="https://cnn.com" id="link4">attr onClick works</a><br/>
```

Comment: hmmm ya this on click might work but i need to add onclick attribute automatically it as page load because i have to avoid ajax page loading through it as due to ajax some scripts are not loaded properly

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "automatically" my code is executed on page load

Comment: @mplugjan , thanks the alternative solved the problem , but am curious why my jquery selection queries not able to add onclick attribute to hyperlink ? i played with a lot so am curious something wrong with my selection queries

Comment: so magic is that with prop you cant add onClick , you have to use attr  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the `href` property of an element you just need to use `prop()`. You don't need to create a separate click handler for it.

Also note that all of the conditions you create boil down to a single one: if the href contains `contact#faq`. As such you can use a single attribute selector.

Lastly `load()` is not an event handler. You need to use `on('load')` instead. Try this:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('a[href*="contact#faq"]').prop('href', 'https://useotools.com');
});
```

It's also worth noting that the `window.load` event is not the same as `document.ready`, so you may want to change that event handler depending on your exact needs.

Comment: thank that on click was just to prevent ajax redirection , however i tried you code but its not working i checked on codepen , am curious why these jquery selection queries not working :( :  https://imgur.com/81XukOY         https://codepen.io/Zelda99/pen/poJxmEL

Comment: Ah, `load()` should be `on('load', fn)`, as `load()` is not an event handler. I've updated the answer. Here's a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8fzawmsx/